# shadowOffset in UITableViewCell Causes slowness when scroll

Tags: objective-c

I have UITable with cell:

[image]

when I scroll in the table I fell slow and fragmentation when table reload

when I remove the shadow code, the slow and fragmentation gone.
but I need the shadow.

```
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1,1);
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Comment: try images with a shadow feel :)

Comment: its just a hack you can set cell background image with a shadow

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `shadowPath` on layer property. Specifying an explicit path usually improves rendering performance.

```
 self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1,1);
 self.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
 self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
 self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5; 
 self.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:10].CGPath;
```

Using `self.bounds` as a path rect, make sure that view's frame is already set.

Comment: its work but     self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1,1);
not work.

Comment: @RoeiNadam what you mean `CGSizeMake(-1,1)` not work. Is performance improved? Is shadow visible? Please elaborate.